# Mutually dependent functions in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

In Asymptote, I have a function `f` which calls a function `g` and `g` calls `f`. If I proceed like in C/C++:

```
real g(real);

real f(real x) {
    return g(......);
}

real g(real x) {
    return f(......);
}
```

then the compilation of this code runs fine. But if I call e.g. `g(1)`, I get an error:

> dereference of null function

How to proceed? Is it possible?

Comment: Not everyone knows C/C++. Can you give a specific situation arising that problem?

Comment: I just meant such a situation works in C/C++. But my pseudo-example is not good: obviously it produces an infinite loop. Anyway I solved the problem by replacing g in f with its expression.